# nix attribute not found setting up Dapp repo

Tags: plutus, nix

I modified slightly  cabal.project of the  plutus-apps to serve as base for my own application repo. It includes another repo of my own that is also a sligh modification of the plutus repo. If my own git repo that substitutes plutus is xxxx. Now this error happens when executing nix-shell

> nix-shell
> error: attribute 'xxxx' missing....

I suppose that this attribute should be added somewhere in flakes or some other nix configuration but I had no clue.  Looking for information I figured out and I added it to flake.nix. Since my repo is a modification of Plutus, I put it instead of the plutus repo

```
plutus-core = {
  url = "github:agocorona/plutus"; #"github:input-output-hk/plutus"
  flake = false;
};
```

But the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I Finally got the solution here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/haskell.nix/issues/1427